# [Netbeans 8.2]error converting my .jar file using IKVM

Tags: java, netbeans, exe, ikvm

I have an error in my Netbeans 8.2 that stated:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

and I think that that is the reason why I couldn't convert it to ikvm using cmd

> Could not find or load main class C:\Users[username]\Desktop\folder\Create\dist\Create.jar

any help here?

my java code goes like this:

```java
import java.io.*;
public class Create {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        boolean flag = false;
        int i = 0;

        File stockFile = new File("c://Users/[username]/folder/" + args[i] + ".txt");

        try{
            flag = stockFile.createNewFile();
        }catch (IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("Error while creating File" + ioe);
        }

        System.out.println("File " + stockFile.getPath() + " created ");
    }

}
```